# Jest & Enzyme test error with React Context API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a React app with Jest & Enzyme. When I run `npm run test` I get the error in `UserContext.jsx` that is imported in `MainPage.jsx`. How can I fix that?

Error message

Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
      11 | };
      12 | 
    > 13 | export const useUserValue = () => useContext(UserContext);
         |                                   ^
```

UserContext.jsx

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => {
    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
};

export const useUserValue = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

MainPage.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'jest-styled-components';

import { configure, shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import MainPage from "./MainPage";
import {useUserValue} from "../Context/UserContext";

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Main Page Component', () => {

    it('exists', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MainPage />, {context: useUserValue()});
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

MainPage.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useUserValue} from "../Context/UserContext";

export default function MainPage(props) {
    const [{ user }, dispatch] = useUserValue();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
           {user.name}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says what is the problem:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Here the hook is incorrectly used outside the component:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MainPage />, {context: useUserValue()});
```

It should have been `{context: someContext }`, but the problem is that Enzyme renderer accepts a context for legacy React context that cannot affect context consumers and functional components in particular.

Currently [`shallow` doesn't support context providers](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2176) and needs to use `mount`:

```
const wrapper = mount(
 <UserContext.Provider value={...}>
   <MainPage />
 </UserContext.Provider>
);
```

Since `useUserValue` is located in its own module, it could be tested separately and mocked in components where it's used, this way it can be used with `shallow`.

This error can also occur if there are multiple copies or mismatching versions of React and ReactDOM, but this is not the case.

Comment: With this approach, method calls from test case onto the wrapper component, in this case MainPage would fail stating method is not found...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The question doesn't contain methods in the comp. If you have a similar case that the answer doesn't address then consider asking a new question.